# React problem with implementation (two items to one value)

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to get something like cart, so the values will be counted times quantity, ive "modded" something like this, but this doesnt work:

I will start with the API response:

```
    "magazyn": [
      {
        "productId": 1,
        "productGUID": "491a8965545a4071bda2811094cf55d1",
        "productSKU": 10,
        "productTitle": "aaaaaa",
        "productCategory": "string",
        "productDescription": "string",
        "productQuantity": 1,
        "productVatRate": 1,
        "productNettoPurchasePrice": 1,
        "productNettoSellingPrice": 1,
        "productNettoSalesMargin": 1,
        "productBruttoSellingPrice": 1,
        "productNettoIncomeValue": 1,
        "productVolume": "Szt"
      },
      {
        "productId": 2,
        "productGUID": "21a63a6a0ff84cb0b1b476284ffe7368",
        "productSKU": 13,
        "productTitle": "absddad",
        "productCategory": "string",
        "productDescription": "string",
        "productQuantity": 2,
        "productVatRate": 2,
        "productNettoPurchasePrice": 2,
        "productNettoSellingPrice": 2,
        "productNettoSalesMargin": 2,
        "productBruttoSellingPrice": 38,
        "productNettoIncomeValue": 2,
        "productVolume": "Szt"
      }
    ],
    "productId": [
      {
        "pcID": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
        "productId": 1,
        "productQuantity": 5
      },
      {
        "pcID": "6b29fc40-ca47-1067-b31d-00dd010662da",
        "productId": 2,
        "productQuantity": 4
      }
    ]
```

```
{item.productId.map(val => (
 item.magazyn.map((item2) => item2.productBruttoSellingPrice).reduce((previousValue, currentValue2) => {
return previousValue + currentValue2 * val.productQuantity;
}, 0)
))}
```

I also tried with

```
{item.productId.map((val) => val.productQuantity).reduce(firstVal, nextVal) => {
 item.magazyn.map((item2) => item2.productBruttoSellingPrice).reduce((previousValue, currentValue2) => {
return previousValue + currentValue2 * val;
}, 0)
},0)
)}
```

But the first one gives weird values like, for example when the result is 30 this gives me 3030, the second attempt is gives nothing :P

my problem is that, the magazyn give me the product price, but the "productId" object gives me a quantity, i want to merge it like when productId.productId == magazyn.productId then productQuantity * productBruttoSellingPrice and this one will be in the loop because we have different items in "productId" object.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the following? Do I interpret what you are expecting?

```
const magazyn = [...item.magazyn];
const productId = [...item.productId];

let sum = 0;
magazyn.forEach((value1) => {
  productId.forEach((value2) => {
    if (value1.productId === value2.productId){
        sum= sum + 
value1.productBruttoSellingPrice * 
value2.productQuantity
    } 
  });
});

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: The problem is that i would to put the logic inside the <td> in the table to get only a return with a result ^^

Comment: Also this is not what i want, i just want to get the sum of the prices, i mean:
You have 3 items in cart for example, and this is a "item1, item2, item3" all of those items are the arrays objects with id and quantity, next you have another array of objects names warehouse for example, where you have an iformation for example about the item1, that he has the 300 dollar price, so now you know the price, and quantity and i want to get the result of multiplication :)

Comment: And another problem is that, the item.magazyn is also from .map
its like data.map(item =>())

Comment: Anyway with your solution problem is still the same, for example if i have two items in one order and i want to print those values im getting something like string with value 1 and value 2, for example 3+2 will be 5, but i've got 32 all the time :P

Comment: I mean look:
https://imgur.com/a/VcVMRz1
I just want to make those two values add to themselves >_<

Comment: @3milBow I've updated my answer. In map method, it returns an array created by the callback inside it, so calculation is not appropriate.

Comment: It's work, but the second answer is better, i mean less complicated, so thank you so much for you time! :)

Comment: @3milBow Thanks to confirming it. I agree with you, mine was not cool and smart.